# How to Convert Decimal to Binary without toBinary in java?

Tags: binary

I'm confused on how one can get this to work without using toBinary().

Thanks!

I have tried one thing like using while loops but it hasn't been working for me. Can you guys please help me.

while
{

}

Comment: Welcome to SO! You may want to provide your code and sample data. Then, you would receive more support.

Comment: Im so lost I really don't know what I am doing right now.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int toBin(int dec) {
    StringBuffer bin = new StringBuffer();
    while(true) {
        bin = AddCharToFront((dec%2==1 ? '1':'0'),bin);
        if(dec<=1) {
            return Integer.parseInt(bin.toString());
        }
        dec/=2;
    }
}
public static StringBuffer AddCharToFront(char newChar,StringBuffer currentStringBuffer) {
    StringBuffer a = new StringBuffer(new Character(newChar).toString());
    a.append(currentStringBuffer);
    return a;
}
```

This code uses a fairly simple method to do so. It still returns a decimal number though, but in binary format. To call it, use `toBin(//Your Decimal Number Here)`.

Comment: More accurately, because the `toBin(int dec)` function returns an `int`, use `int someInteger = toBin(int dec)`.